# Failure: org.apache.maven plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:test-jar

Tags: java, maven, opendaylight

I'm trying to compile a project but I'm running into a Maven plugin error.

I use Apache Maven 3.3.9 and `java-9-openjdk`, with the command

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
```

but that fails with the following message:

> Error: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:test-jar

Do I have to modify my pom file?

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <sourcepath>*/target/generated-sources/mdsal-binding/*</sourcepath>
          <excludePackageNames>*</excludePackageNames>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the mention of `mdsal-binding` in your POM, you’re trying to build an [OpenDaylight](https://www.opendaylight.org) project (I’m guessing either `coretutorials` or `transportpce`) with JDK 9. We don’t support that yet; you must build with JDK 8.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using **-DskipTests=true** it is trying to avoid test.
That subsequently fails to generate the test-jar.

Either you could comment out the ***test jar goal***.
Else do not skip the tests.